# Chrome adds unwanted margin to body

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I recently got started with building websites in wordpress, I got tired of building CMS back-ends myself. To start it off nicely i decided to build my portfolio (still in progress, I might add), but for some reason Chrome adds a weird margin to the top of my website. Every other browser handles the website just fine (even safari, also webkit). I used a CSS reset form to get rid of all the margins, but this one is really breaking my balls. Any help on how to remove this?

**Update:**

For anyone landing on this poorly formulated question: the reason for this whitespace was because I didn't put the `wp_header()` and `wp_footer()` in the header and footer respectively. This caused Wordpress to add margin for an admin bar, but no hooks to render it. The link I've added previously doesn't relate to the question anymore and I removed it.

Comment: It seems as if Chromium, also, **doesn't** add extra margin (tested on Ubuntu 11.04).

Comment: Can't see a margin in Chrome here.

Comment: Same here, there's a couple of pixels between the top of the page and the top of the icons

Comment: thx for the input, i've got it working correctly after messing around with the css. Maybe chrome cached the css, or not, anyway: problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine in Chrome here. There are however some errors in the markup that you would want to fix to be on the safe side. You can never be sure how browsers react to incorrect code.

It's mostly that you have anchor tags around your list elements instead of the other way around.

[Validation result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.danielsneijers.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)